# Сделать выбранным радиобаттон в настройках программы

Tags: xml, android, java

Собственно вопрос, вывожу я все это в ListPreferences вот так:
**prefs.xml**

```
<ListPreference android:title="@string/Title" 
android:summary="@string/Summary"
android:key="PreferenceKey"
android:defaultValue="VALUE_2"
android:entries="@array/Entries"
android:entryValues="@array/Values" />
```

**array.xml:**

```
<string-array name="Entries">
            <item>@string/Value1</item>
            <item>@string/Value2</item>
            <item>@string/Value2</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="Values">
            <item>VALUE_1</item>
            <item>VALUE_2</item>
            <item>VALUE_3</item>
</string-array>
```

как мне задать выбранным например из Entries value1 ? Поискал в интернете, ничего не нашел и решил обратиться к вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListPreference android:title="@string/Title" 
android:summary="@string/Summary"
android:key="PreferenceKey"
android:defaultValue="VALUE_2"
android:entries="@array/Entries"
android:entryValues="@array/Values" 
android:defaultValue="value1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListPreference android:title="@string/Title" 
android:summary="@string/Summary"
android:key="PreferenceKey"

android:entries="@array/Entries"
android:entryValues="@array/Values" 
android:defaultValue="value1" />
```

или

```
setValueIndex(int index);
```

или

```
    CheckBoxPreference dualCoreModePref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("PreferenceKey");
dualCoreModePref.setChecked(getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(dualCoreModePref.getKey(), 1));
```

Comment: чет не понятно куда это вставлять)

Answer (score 0):

мне кажеться нужно создать файл ява Prefs.java  в нем "указать" на prefs.xml и связать с Main.java c Prefs.java.